# Minimum force needed to start a wheel on a slope?

Tags: forces, geometry

I have been messing up with this for at least two hours , but can seem to find anything rather than a small angle!

[image: Question]

The question is to find the magnitude and the direction of the smallest force  (say P) that is required to just start the wheel having radius (60cm) over the block?

Height of block is = 15 units
Weight of wheel = 10kN

The farthest i have gone with this is to find a single angle:
[image]

Comment: Forget about the wheel.  It's just a lever, with the corner of the block as a fulcrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of contact between block and wheel can be considered axis of rotation. P force is creating a counter clockwise (beneficial) moment and mg is opposing. Normal force between plane and wheel should be considered zero.

Therefore, optimal P direction should be perpendicular to the line between contact point and center of wheel. Next, equate the moment created by mg to that created by P.